# Can I select multiple ranges in an Ace editor?

Tags: ace-editor

Can I select *multiple* ranges in an Ace editor? I don't want to use markers in this case, I want to set more than one selection in the editor. I have this code:

```
selectedCodeBlocks.forEach(selectedCodeBlock => {
  const aceRange = new AceRange(selectedCodeBlock.startRow, selectedCodeBlock.startColumn, selectedCodeBlock.endRow, selectedCodeBlock.endColumn);
  this.aceEditor.getSelection().setSelectionRange(aceRange, false);
});
```

but it only seems to select the last one. Can I select all of them?

Answer (score 1):

It appears this does the trick for selecting multiple ranges:

```
this.aceEditor.getSelection().addRange(aceRange);
```

Comment: There are also `editor.selection.fromJSON` method that accept list of ranges. And `toJSON` which serialises selection to an object that can be passed to JSON.stringify